# Api suggestion for location finding

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, foursquare

I have a growing index of company names, city and state (Sometimes zip/neighborhood, but specifically never address) that I need to get the lat long pair / address for so I can show them on a map.

Anyone have a suggestion the best api to do this with? (its going to be done ~100k times)

Comment: If you don't have address, I doubt you will be able to get meaningful lat/lng.

Comment: Possibly you will not find a free API for that number of requests per day. See https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing?hl=pt-br and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx

Comment: I do have a name and a city and am willing to accept the first result of a search if those will be reasonably accurate.

Comment: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?v=20120321&query=Financial%20Times&intent=browse&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d124941735&near=New%20York%2C%20NY

Comment: Why don't you geocode the addresses when you store them in the database? Then you can manually adjust it if necessary.  [Geocoding strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat)

Comment: I dont have addresses, part of the spec is getting the addresses.

Answer (score -1):

you can easily do it by using the google's location Library.
The complete documentation and tutorial video is at 
[Google Maps Javascript API at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)